# How to fill an array based on users input in a single line

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of 3 and want to fill it with users input at once(not to ask for input twice)

```java
Scanner myArray = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please R and C with two spaces in between:");
inputs[i] = myArray.nextInt();
R = (inputs[0]);
C = (inputs[3]);
```

but I am receiving error for assigning `C = (inputs[3]);`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Array of 3 has index 0, 1, 2.

Comment: Have you looked at String split? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) (regex would be \s{2}) - but you could use regex with (\d+)\s{2}(\d+) as well and use the capture groups  https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure if what you showed is an abridged version of your code, but here is how to resolve your problem.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please R and C with two spaces in between: ");
int R = scanner.nextInt();
int C = scanner.nextInt();
```

If you absolutely need an array, then do this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please R and C with two spaces in between:");
int[] inputs = {scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt()};
int R = inputs[0];
int C = inputs[1];
```

Note: the space is skipped unless you use `nextLine()`